# Laravel Error: missing required parameter

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling, laravel-8

When I want to edit the post, I get Missing Required Parameter error, How can I fix that?

> Missing required parameter for [Route: cms.edit] [URI: cms/{cm}/edit]
> [Missing parameter: cm]. (View:
> C:\xampp\htdocs\mycmsL\resources\views\cms\edit.blade.php)

This is **articlesController**:

```
public function edit(Article $article)
    {
        return view('cms.edit')
        ->with('article',$article)
        ->with('categories',Category::all())
        ->with('tags',Tag::all());
    }
```

And **edit.blade.php**:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('cms.edit',['id'=> $article->id]) }}"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
@csrf 
@method('put')

<div class="mb-3">
  <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" id="title" value="$article->title">
</div>
<div class="mb-3">
  <textarea  type="text" class="form-control" id="description" name="description" rows="5" value="$article->description"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="mb-3">
  <input type="file" class="form-control" name="image" id="image" value="$article->image">
</div>
<div class="mb-3">
  <textarea type="text" name="content" class="form-control" id="content" rows="15"  value="$article->content"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="mb-3">
  <select class="form-select" name="tag" aria-label="Default select example">

      @foreach ($tags as $tag) ?>
        <option value="{{$tag->id}}"> {{$tag->name}} </option>
      @endforeach
  </select>
</div>
  <div class="mb-3">
    <select class="form-select" name="category" aria-label="Default select example">
      @foreach ($categories as $category) ?>
        <option value="{{$category->id}}"> {{$category->name}} </option>
      @endforeach
    </select>
  </div>
  
<button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This is my route:

```
  Route::resource('cms',articlesController::class);
```

and `{{dd($article->id)}}` returning me `null` when I want to see data .

Comment: it should be `route('cms.edit',['cms'=> $article->id])` you can verify that key name by `php artisan route:list`  read here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller

Comment: @KamleshPaul `cm`, not `cms`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use same param url name in the function also

```php
//Change this from 
{{ route('cms.edit',['id'=> $article->id]) }}
//TO
{{ route('cms.edit',['cm'=> $article->id]) }}

public function edit(Article $cm) // old param name '$article' 
    {
        return view('cms.edit')
        ->with('article',$cm)
        ->with('categories',Category::all())
        ->with('tags',Tag::all());
    }
```

Comment: `[URI: cms/{cm}/edit] [Missing parameter: cm]` The parameter is named `cm`, not `cms`

Comment: changed the name param

Comment: i used cm and cms but error was not fixed. [and `{{dd($article->id)}}` returning me null when I want to see data .]